# Publish multiple Jax-WS webservice implementations with same endpoint interface

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, soap, jax-ws

I must offer multiple webservices, each one at diferent url but implementing the same wsdl interface definition. I'm working with JAX-WS and servlet contexts in Tomcat 8.

Tomcat fails to start the context thows an exception:

```
"GMBAL702: Exception in register"
```

---

<<***Implementations***>>

**WsFirstImpl.java**

```
package org.testws;
 ...
@WebService(serviceName="MyWS",
        portName = "MyWSEndPoint",
        endpointInterface = "org.test.ws.impl.IMyWSEndPoint",
        targetNamespace = "http://impl.ws.application.org.test",
        wsdlLocation = "WEB-INF/wsdl/wsdef.wsdl")
public class WsFirstImpl {
 ...
}
```

**WsSecondImpl.java**

```
package org.testws;
 ...
@WebService(serviceName="MyWS",
        portName = "MyWSEndPoint",
        endpointInterface = "org.test.ws.impl.IMyWSEndPoint",
        targetNamespace = "http://impl.ws.application.org.test",
        wsdlLocation = "WEB-INF/wsdl/wsdef.wsdl")
public class WsSecondImpl {
 ...
}
```

---

<<***JAX-WS config***>>

**sun-jaxws.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoints version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime">
    <endpoint implementation="org.testws.WsFirstImpl"
            name="impl1" url-pattern="/ws/firstws" />
<endpoint implementation="org.testws.WsSecondImpl"
            name="impl2" url-pattern="/ws/secondws" />
</endpoints>
```

---

I can't figure what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

Please run again with the following system property setting:

or set

> -Dcom.sun.xml.ws.monitoring.registrationDebug=NORMAL